# Use VMWare Workstation with different Internet Connection?

Tags: router, virtual-machine, vmware

I have 2 different ISPs installed at my home with two different modems/routers and I'm trying to figure out a way I can use them separately on the same PC.

Right now to try and accomplish this, I have a virtual machine installed. So while I'm running my Windows Vista OS, I can have my virtual machine running minimized at the same time. However, they both use the same Internet connection using the bridged option.

Is there anyway I can use a different Internet connection for my normal PC and the virtual machine in it? My computer has an Ethernet card, and a wireless card for hardware. I was thinking maybe I could just connect wirelessly with one of them, but then not the other. But I'm not too sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one of those sub-$20 wi-fi router/bridge/gateway combinations, connect that to the 2nd wi-fi network, and to your PC using the ethernet card, and so have access to one network on the wireless, and another on ethernet. You can then configure the VM connection to use one, or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help! As for what you're describing, are you talking about those usb wireless adapters for PCs that don't have the hardware for Wifi? If so, I can definitely get one of those. Although I'm wondering if it's overkill when my computer already has the 2 pieces of hardware. In either scenario I'm not too sure how I could set it up either. I wish I knew more about VMware/computer/network stuff :(

Comment: No, I'm talking about actual mini-routers, like the TP-Link WR700 (http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR700N) - note: I do not recommend this item in particular, just added it as an example. I found one for $17 that I use for Arduino projects.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm so unsavvy on the subject. But what does the item you mentioned do differently than any of the routers I already have?

Comment: By the way, would you be able to provide any advice on where I could configure the VM connection? It seems like the virtual machine just automatically grabs whatever connection the PC is using when choosing the "bridged" option. The other options are NAT, HOST-only, custom, and they don't seem to be helpful. Although I do notice I have some connections (VMnet1/8) under my network connection. Not sure how I could link them up to one of my routers though--or better yet, my ethernet or wireless card)

Comment: What I offered is not a USB wifi adapter, rather a real router.

Comment: I know. But what I'm saying is that I already have 3 routers in my home. Do I need the 4th one?

Comment: No, you can use any router you want.